# How to set textBox.Text=radCombo.Text in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I am having a `<telerik:RadComboBox>` and a `<asp:TextBox>` in my form. i want to display `textBox.Text=radCombo.Text` in client side on `Textchange event` of the comboBox. i am using the code for this as:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboSample" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" runat="server" Skin="WebBlue" Text ="sample" OnClientKeyPressing  ="func()">
                  </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSample"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func() {
            var cbo = document.getElementById("cboSample");
            document.getElementById("txtSample").Text = cbo.getAttribute("Text");                               
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

what i am doing wrong? how can i achieve the goal

Comment: is your `func()` firing?

Comment: i checked it by placing alert(); but it is not firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below solution

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" OnClientDropDownClosing="OnClientDropDownClosing1">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Invoice" runat="server" Selected="true" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Quote" runat="server" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Invoice">
    </asp:Label>



    <script type="text/javascript">  
     function OnClientDropDownClosing1(sender, args) {
            var label = document.getElementById("Label1");
            label.textContent = sender._selectedItem._text;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: i need to change it on either in the keypress or in text change event. is it possible?

Comment: @Trouble yes it can be done on keypress use onclientkeypressing    and for text change use useonclienttextchange="OnClientTextChange" you can get  more events on below link http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-onclientkeypressing.html